# Terraform databricks labs provider

Tags: azure, file, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I have an issue with terraform databricks labs provider, the below code give me an error
"status 400: err Response from server {"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Path must be absolute: databricks"}
"
There is nothing in documentation about path parameter, I tried without "dbfs:" bit it did not like it as well ?
Any help would be welcome.

```
resource "databricks_dbfs_file" "log4j_files" {
  content = filebase64("${path.module}/log.txt")
  path = "dbfs://databricks/spark-log"
  overwrite = true
  mkdirs = true
  validate_remote_file = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to use the latest version. Format of error message suggests you're using something before version 0.2.3.

Please do use `source` syntax of dbfs file resource, as shown [this example for integration tests](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/scripts/azvnet-integration/databricks.tf):

```
resource "databricks_dbfs_file" "show_variables" {
  source = "${path.module}/log.txt"
  path = "dbfs:/path/to/log.txt"
}
```

Comment: I will double check version,

Comment: @Kylo current version is 0.2.7

Answer (score 1):

The path parameter needs to include the filename.

Here's the documentation you'll need as well: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/dbfs_file

Comment: I know I did check it but it is not working, at least the version I have. I will have to get my hands dirty and check in source code,

Comment: Does the path format shown in the documentation not work? I believe you'll also need the content_b64_md5 argument.

Comment: When I add content_b64_md5 it throws an error, It must be something with the version. It is very buggy.